# Autocomplete :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

The error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'
>   in"

is showing in Google chrome console

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trackerid").change(function() {
    var var_locoid = $("#trackerid option:selected").val();
    //  alert(var_locoid);
    $("#deliverylocation").autocomplete({

      source: function(request, response) {
        var auto_data = $("#deliverylocation").val();
        // alert(auto_data);

        //alert(var_locoid);
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/CodeProject/Testctrl/lookup",
          type: "POST",
          datatype: "json",
          //returnType:"json",
          data: {
            'var_locoid': var_locoid,
            'auto_data': auto_data
          },
          success: function(data) {
            var resp = $.map(data, function(obj) {
              return obj.tag;
            });

            response(resp);
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 1
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try  alert(data); at the top of your success function to verify what data you get back.

Comment: The `in` operator only works on objects. You are using it on a `string`. Make sure your value is an `object` before you using `$.map`. I believe, in your case, you will have to parse `data` before using in `$.map`... `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 2):

The in operator only works on objects. You are using it on a string. Make sure your value is an object before you using $.map. In this specific case, you have to parse the JSON:

```
$.map(JSON.parse(data), ...);
```